# FileUtil.copy is working in HA mode hdfs

Tags: hadoop

I am copying files from local to hdfs in HA mode but it is giving following exception:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: nameservices
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.<init>(Client.java:195)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:850)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:720)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:359)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:207)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:170)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1378)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1390)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:196)
```

And my java code for HDFS write is :

```
        Path srcPath = new Path(
        LookupFileHelper.getLocalFileLocation(section));
        LOGGER.info("Uploading srcPath " + srcPath.toUri());
        FileSystem srcFS = FileSystem.get(srcPath.toUri(), conf);
        LOGGER.info("Uploading srcFS name" + srcFS.getName());
        LOGGER.info("Uploading srcFS " + srcFS);

        Path dstPath = new Path(section.getDestLocationHdfs());
        LOGGER.info("Uploading dstPath " + section.getDestLocationHdfs());
        URI uri = URI.create(section.getDestLocationHdfs());
        LOGGER.info("Uploading dstPath " + uri);
        FileSystem dstFS = FileSystem.get(uri, conf);
        LOGGER.info("Uploading dstPath " + dstFS);

        FileUtil.copy(srcFS, srcPath, dstFS, dstPath, false, conf);
```

Comment: Have you entered the hostname of your namenode in your /etc/hosts?

Comment: yes i added and it HA(high availability) hadoop cluster.

Comment: Please share how you are creating conf object.

Comment: Configuration conf = new Configuration(false);
                conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "nameservice");
        conf.set("fs.default.name", conf.get("fs.defaultFS"));
        conf.set("dfs.nameservices","nameservicename");
        conf.set("dfs.ha.namenodes.namesrvicename", "namenode1,namenode2");
        conf.set("dfs.namenode.rpc-address.namesrvicename.namenode1","abc:8020");
        conf.set("dfs.namenode.rpc-address.namesrvicename.namenode2","xyz:8020");